# Analytical solution of a system of two nonlinear ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, matlab, nonlinear-system

I would like to solve a system of two nonlinear coupled ODES with boundary conditions.

The equations are given below.

$$f^{'''}+\frac{12}{5}ff^{'}-\frac{4}{5}(f^{'})^{2}+\phi = 0$$
$$\phi^{'}+\frac{12}{5}f\phi =0$$

With boundary conditions
$$\phi^{'}(0) = f^{''}(0)=f(0)=1-\phi(0) =0$$

And
$$f(\infty) = \phi(\infty) =0$$

Is it possible to solve this problem analytically?

**What I have done:**

I have tried "dsolve" in MATLAB but failed to get a solution.

Comment: Should there be a second derivative in the second term? It seems improbable that a symbolic solution exists. I think this is what you mean, not that the solution can be expanded into a power series everywhere?